# inject a JPA repository in Spring Boot test, without session issue

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-boot-test

I am adding some tests on my Spring Boot 2.4 application that works well in production.

In one of my `SpringBootTest` , I call the API (using `mockMvc`) and compare the result with what I have in the DB.

```java
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class TicketIT {


    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Autowired
    private TicketTypeRepository ticketTypeRepository;
    
    
    @Test
    void shouldReturnListOfTicketTypes() throws Exception {
    
    RequestBuilder request =
        MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(RESOURCE_BASE_URL + "/types").contentType(APPLICATION_JSON);

    String responseAsString =
        mockMvc
            .perform(request)
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andReturn()
            .getResponse()
            .getContentAsString();

    List<TicketTypesRepresentation> ticketTypes =
        objectMapper.readValue(
            responseAsString, new TypeReference<List<TicketTypesRepresentation>>() {
            });

    assertThat(ticketTypes).hasSameSizeAs(ticketTypeRepository.findAll());

    }
}
```

I have the feeling I've written that type of tests hundreds of times, but on this one, I am facing a problem : my application is configured correctly, because I receive a list of items in the API response.

However, what I find strange is that I get an exception from the `ticketTypeRepository.findAll()` call :

> failed to lazily initialize a collection of role ... could not initialize proxy - no Session

I understand the issue, and I can fix it either by making the relation eager (with `@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)` on the entity), or my making the test `@Transactional` but I am not sure I like any of the options..

I don't remember facing that issue in the past in other Spring Boot tests so I am a bit puzzled.

Am I missing something to make sure that all the calls made to ticketTypeRepository are made within a transaction ?  `TicketTypeRepository` is a wrapper around a `CrudRepository`, is it the reason why it doesn't work directly ?

Here's the entity and repository code :

```java
    public class JpaTicketTypeRepository implements TicketTypeRepository {

    public List<TicketType> findAll() {

        var allTicketTypesEntity= jpaTicketTypesEntityRepository.findAll();

        return StreamSupport.stream(allTicketTypesEntity.spliterator(), false)
                .map(TicketTypeEntity::toTicketTypeList)
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
                .stream().flatMap(List::stream)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

    }
}
```

and the entity (simplified) :

```java
    @Table(name = "TICKET_TYPES")
    @Entity
    @Slf4j
    public class TicketTypeEntity {

      @Id
      private Long id;

      @OneToMany
      @JoinTable(name = "TICKET_TYPES_GROUPS",
          joinColumns =
              {@JoinColumn(name = "TICKET_TYPE_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")},
          inverseJoinColumns =
              {@JoinColumn(name = "TICKET_GROUP_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")})
      @Nonnull
      private List<TicketGroupsEntity> ticketGroupsEntity;

      @Nonnull
      public List<TicketType> toTicketTypeList() {

        log.info("calling toTicketTypeList for id "+id);
        log.info("     with size : "+ticketGroupsEntity.size());

        return ticketGroupsEntity.stream().map(group -> TicketType.builder()
            .id(id)
            .build()).collect(Collectors.toList());
      }
    }
```

The exception happens the first time `size()` is called on the collection :

> failed to lazily initialize a collection of role:
> my.service.database.entities.TicketTypeEntity.ticketGroupsEntity,
> could not initialize proxy - no Session
> org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize
> a collection of role:
> my.service.database.entities.TicketTypeEntity.ticketGroupsEntity,
> could not initialize proxy - no Session   at
> org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:606)
> at
> org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:218)
> at
> org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.readSize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:162)
> at
> org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.size(PersistentBag.java:371)
> at
> my.service.database.entities.TicketTypeEntity.toTicketTypeList(TicketTypeEntity.java:78)
> at
> java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
> at
> java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1655)
> at
> java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
> at
> java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
> at
> java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
> at
> java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
> at
> java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
> at
> my.service.database.JpaTicketTypeRepository.findAll(JpaTicketTypeRepository.java:29)

Comment: It's puzzling as taking size of a `ticketTypeRepository.findAll()` should not trigger materializing lazy collections - you are only counting instances, not touching their fields. Could you post a full stack trace of the issue?

Comment: I've added details in the post. I realize that what may be confusing is that ticketTypeRepository is a wrapper around a Jpa repository, but not a JPA repository itself. Maybe that's the difference with the "usual" code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you mis-interpret the stack trace. The problem is not in calling the method `size()` on the result of `findAll()`, but in the method `findAll` itself.

In `findAll` you call `TicketTypeEntity.toTicketTypeList`, which converts DB entity to DTO. This method touches `ticketGroupsEntity`, which is a lazy collection.

The code fails in unit test, but runs when accessed via springs controller.
This is due to Open Session In View, which is enabled by default.

See:

- [A Guide to Spring’s Open Session In View](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-open-session-in-view)
- [The Open Session In View Anti-Pattern](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-open-session-in-view-anti-pattern/)

You could solve it multiple ways:

- @Transactional findAll (be aware of lazy loading issues)
- explicit fetch in query
- entityGraph

But to my eyes your entity mapping looks suspicious, you seem to have all data needed to construct TicketType in TicketGroupsEntity. Maybe you could query that entity instead?